# CSS3 Style button: how can I make a button fades away while playing

Tags: css, button

I have been trying to style a CSS3 button that currently activates on hover and each time it gets stopped/started it fades. I am trying to modify the current code in order for the play button to fade away only on click (play/pause action)

Here is the code:

```
 .play-button {
        background-color: rgb(80,80,80);
        border: 2px solid rgb(136,136,136);
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
        position: absolute;
        border-radius: 30px;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin: -30px;
        cursor: pointer;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
        transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;

        &:hover {
            opacity: 3;
        }
    }

    .play-button:before {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        background: transparent;
        border: 14px solid transparent;
        top: 16px;
        left: 25px;
        height: 0;
        border-right-color: transparent;
        border-top-color: transparent;
        border-bottom-color: transparent;
        border-right: 0;
        -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
        transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
    }

    .play-button:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        border: 14px solid white;
        top: 15px;
        left: 24px;
        height: 0;
        border-right-color: transparent;
        border-top-color: transparent;
        border-bottom-color: transparent;
        border-right: 0;
        -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
        transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
    }

    .play-button.pause:before {
        border: 4px solid white;
        top: 18px;
        left: 18px;
        height: 16px;
    }

    .play-button.pause:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        border: 4px solid white;
        top: 18px;
        left: 33px;
        height: 16px;
    }
```

If I modify .play-button as follows, the button will be fixed, but then it does not fade away on click, meaning that it stays over the animated gif while it is playing:

```
.play-button {
            background-color: rgb(80,80,80);
            border: 2px solid rgb(136,136,136);
            width: 60px;
            height: 60px;
            position: absolute;
            border-radius: 30px;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            margin: -30px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
```

How can I change my current to achieve what I want?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in the question itself. Currently you do not have any HTML on which the CSS applies.

Comment: Are you limited to using just HTML/CSS?

Comment: > "`opacity: 3;`".. dude, that's super opaque!